# Prevent text from shifting when hovered

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to flexbox and trying to make a menu using it.

I want links to have a nice border on the bottom when user hovers on them. But even if I set `box-sizing: border-box;` flex keeps recalculating text position and element 'jumps' instead of predicted behaviour.

I have an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAXzxw?editors=1100) with the problem. I don't want content inside my element to jump when I hover.

Is there any simple solution/edition to my code to make it work as expected? I know other ways of achieving what I want: set baseline, use relative/absolute positioning...

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #123;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item:hover {
  border-bottom: 10px solid lightgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  Content
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding a 10px border on hover, you are changing the size of the box on hover. That will reposition surrounding elements... on hover.

One solution is to reserve the space for the border at all times. In other words, have the 10px border factored into the element in a normal state.

This border gets the element's background color (or `transparent`) so it is not visible. On hover, you only change the color.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #123;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
.item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #123;
}
.item:hover::after {
  border-bottom: 10px solid lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use an inset box-shadow for this feature. 
I managed to recreate the effect by changing the `:hover` css to:

```
.item:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px lightgreen;
}
```

[example here](http://codepen.io/CarlRosell/pen/WxdyOz?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

What if you just set a bottom border by default using the same colour which is on its background? Once you hover over your item, you will need just to change the colour.

Comment: Yes it will work, also I can set opacity to 0 and change it to 1 on hover - it will give the same result, but what I don't like about it, is the fact that element will NOT be in center because it will be moved to top by the size of the border.

Comment: Or `border-color: transparent`.