# When hovered, navigation bar elements changing position. Why?

Tags: html, css

So, my goal is to create a simple navigation bar with centered links/elements. I kinda succeeded... Kinda because when i set the floating option it changes spaces between elements and twitches the text out of position (run the snippet to see the efect). 
Wanna have some space between the words, but to stay fixed when floated over or activated/selected.

I tried to make it work with styling only ul and li tags but it didnt work, so i tried placing the li tags into separate divisions. Still no success.

Looked through every possible solution i could think of - adding margins, padding, setting them to auto, looked through similar questions here and around web and i got nothing.

Obviously i'm missing something and i would appreciate your help very much so i can continue working on my website.

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #ccc;
}

.nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 position: fixed;
 height: 85px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #002345;
}

.about {
 font-family: 'Baloo';
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 85px;
 height: 85px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.portfol {
 font-family: 'Baloo';
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 85px;
 height: 85px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.cont {
 font-family: 'Baloo';
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 85px;
 height: 85px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.active {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #002345;
}

a:hover {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 background-color: #777;
 color: #002345;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>PortfolioPage</title>
</head>

<body>

 <header>
 <div class="nav"> 
 <ul>
  <div class="about"> <li><a href="#" class="active" style="text-decoration: none">ABOUT ME</a></li> </div>
  <div class="portfol"> <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">PORTFOLIO</a></li> </div>
  <div class="cont"> <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">CONTACT</a></li> </div>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </header>
  
</body>
```

Comment: remove the 15px left and right padding in your a:hover css code

Comment: When you change the size of a box on hover, it can shift. In this case, you're adding horizontal padding on hover. It's better to factor all dimensions of the box into the normal state. Then on hover only use styles that leave the dimensions alone.

Comment: Here's a very similar question, except the problem was borders, not padding: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38402063/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because you have added padding on the `:hover` state but it is not present in the normale state rule...

```
a {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
a:hover {
    display: block;
    /*padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;*/
    background-color: #777;
    color: #002345;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because in your hover class you are adding padding to the a tag, add them by default like the example

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #ccc;
}

.nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 position: fixed;
 height: 85px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #002345;
}

.about {
 font-family: 'Baloo';
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 85px;
 height: 85px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.portfol {
 font-family: 'Baloo';
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 85px;
 height: 85px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.cont {
 font-family: 'Baloo';
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 85px;
 height: 85px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.active {
 display: block;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #002345;
}
a{
     padding-left: 15px; 
     padding-right: 15px; 
}
a:hover {
 display: block;
 background-color: #777;
 color: #002345;
}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>PortfolioPage</title>
</head>

<body>

 <header>
 <div class="nav"> 
 <ul>
  <div class="about"> <li><a href="#" class="active" style="text-decoration: none">ABOUT ME</a></li> </div>
  <div class="portfol"> <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">PORTFOLIO</a></li> </div>
  <div class="cont"> <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">CONTACT</a></li> </div>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </header>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much (DaFois also), thats what i was doing wrong. Corrected and working as you said! :)
and to remove the space between the boxes i should use the negative margin method or is there something better? You know, to make them side by side with these paddings only...

Answer (score 0):

just remove

```
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
```

from

`a: hover`